# Find the probability of picking a prime number in a range

Tags: java, c++, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, primes

The task is:

From a sub-sequence of integers between 2 inputted numbers A and B, we need to find the probability of picking a prime number. I have written something to accomplish the task-

```
import java.util.*;
class Sample{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cases = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i<cases; i++){
            int l = sc.nextInt();
            int r = sc.nextInt();

            double ans = 0.0;
            for(int j = l; j<=r;j++){
                if(isPrime(j)){
                    ans++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(String.format("output: %.6f",ans/(r-l+1)));

        }

    }
    public static boolean isPrime(int n){
        boolean ans = true;
        if(n == 1){
            ans = false;
        }
        if(n>5&& n%5==0){
            ans = false;
        }
        if(n>2&&n%2 == 0){
            ans = false;
        }
        else{
        for(int i = 3; i<(Math.sqrt(n)+1);i=i+2){
            if(n%i == 0){
                ans = false;
                break;
            }
        }}
        return ans;
    }
}
```

We also input an integer (cases) to represent the number of test cases.
This gives a correct answer on my machine, but gets a time limit exceeded verdict when I upload it. I thought that maybe using c++ would solve the issue.

So I made a similar program in c++, but still it does not match the time limit of 1 second. The C++ code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
bool isPrime(int n){
    bool ans= true;
    if(n == 1){
        ans = false;
    }
    if(n > 2 && n%2 == 0){
        ans = false;
    }
    for (int i = 3; i < (pow(n,0.5)+1); ++i)
    {
        if(n%i == 0){
            ans = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
int main(){
    int cases;
    cin>> cases;
    for(int i = 0;i<cases;i++){
        int a, b , ans = 0;
        cin>> a,b;
        for (int j = a; j <= b; ++j)
        {
            if(isPrime(j)){
                ans ++;
            }
        }
        double d = ans/(r-l+1);
        cout<<d;
    }

}
```

Constraints:

1 ≤ Cases ≤ 100000

1 ≤ A≤ B ≤ 1000000

How can I optimize it further?

What I researched -

I should check if a i divides n only up till `Math.sqrt(n)+1`. Also I should do `i = i+2` as I have checked for even numbers before only. I should also `break` the loop once `ans` becomes false so as to stop any further unnecessary iterations.

```
for(int i = 3; i<(Math.sqrt(n)+1);i=i+2){
        if(n%i == 0){
            ans = false;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Here is the link to the question: [codechef](https://www.codechef.com/HACF2018/problems/PRA).

Comment: _"How can I optimize it further?"_ Lookup _The sieve of Erasthotenes_.

Comment: Guys please do not down vote the question just because you don't know it. At least notify me in the comments what the question is lacking

Comment: _"... what the question is lacking"_ Research and efforts.

Comment: I have a vague recollection of a formula to estimate the number of prime numbers less than a certain number, which relies on the Riemann hypothesis. Are you sure you need to count them one by one?

Comment: "please do not down vote the question just because you don't know it" That's a dangerous assumption. Questions get downvoted if they lack quality. If anything, difficult questions tend to attract a lot of upvotes if they're well stated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question contains 2 pieces of code which makes it hard to review.

**Issue specific to the C++ code**

Your are using `++i` in your code despite having handled the even numbers explicitely before. It should be `i+=2` like in your Java code.

**Issue in both implementations**

Instead of maintaining an `ans` boolean value, you can simply return false whenever you know that the number can't be prime.

You write your loop like this `for(int i = 3; i<(Math.sqrt(n)+1);i=i+2)` which is likely to compute the square root at each iteration. The compiler may be able to optimize this out but just in case, it is probably better to store it in a variable beforehand.

**Different algorithm**

To know whether many numbers are primes, a convenient and efficient algorithm is to use [The Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to build a table to check primes.

You could build it one and for all to get the primes up to the maximum `r` value.

Going further, you could also build (once) a table giving for each number `n` the number of primes numbers smaller or equal to `n`. Then, for each input (a, b), the frequency is something along the lines of `( primes_up_to(b) - primes_up_to(a) / (b - a)`.